# Jquery $.post not working with Spring MVC 4

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc, jquery-post

Jquery $ .post not working on a project using Spring MVC 4 in IntelliJ IDEA.

I need to send the data to the Controller Spring MVC when the checkbox is checked or unchecked! But the parameters are being sent always "null".

What am I doing wrong?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('input[id="chTarefa"]').change(function () {
                var id = $(this).attr("idTarefa");
                if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                    $.post("checkbox.html", {id: id, estado: "marcado"});
                    alert("Checked");
                }
                else {
                    $.post("checkbox.html", {id: id, estado: "desmarcado"});
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Controller:

```html
@Controller
public class CheckboxController {
    @RequestMapping("checkbox.html")
    public ModelAndView adiciona(String id, String estado) {

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("checkbox");

        if(estado.equals("marcado")){
            mv.addObject("msg", "Finish!");
        }else{
            mv.addObject("msg", "No finish!");
        }
        return mv;
    }
}
```

Html:

```html
<input id="chTarefa" type="checkbox" idTarefa="4" /> Checkbox
```

Comment: You didn't even explain what "not working" means.

Comment: `$(this).attr("idTarefa");` - in HTML isn't attribute `idTarefa`,  but is `id` :-) Do You haven't error in console log in browser?

Comment: @Peter why isn't it an attribute?... it is in the html shown. Most people would use `data-attributeName` but will work as it is shown also

Comment: The @Controller receives the parameters "id" and "estado" always null.

Comment: can you try this : `$.post("checkbox.html", "{id: " + id + ", estado: marcado }");`

Comment: also just curious about `$ .post`, where does it come from?

Comment: @Guile Sorry, I don't see HTML code no mobile. On http://jsfiddle.net/pzLexcqg/  Your HTML and JS code work correctly.

Comment: @erkaner, thanks, but the parameters are still sent as "null".

Comment: @Peter I also did not find any error in Jquery, I believe that can be a problem with Spring MVC.  The parameters are still sent as "null"

Comment: Your controller is missing the proper mapping for that you need to tell it where to get those `String` from add `@RequestParam` to those `String` arguments. Currently they are filled with defaults, `null`, always.